# Optimising resource allocation using random numbers

Tags: algorithm, logic

I have to allocate resources using random numbers between a limit, say 1 to 9. So first, I run a function to get a random number between 1 and 9. Then I check if any resource has been allocated with the index equal to the random number that has been generated. If it hasn't been allocated a resource, I allocate it, otherwise I return to calculate another random number. It works fine, but after a certain point, the efficiency decreases. When I reach to the point where say 5 or 6 resources out of 9 have been allocated, I've to wait for a long time period till I get the remaining allocations. How do I optimise this?

Here's the algorithm:

1. Fetch the resource.
2. Generate a random number.
3. If the position with the index equal to the random number has not been allocated a resource, go to step 4. Else go to 5.
4. Allocate resource to the position with index equal to random number.
5. Go to step 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of generating random numbers inside the loop, preallocate an array containing the indices and [shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) that:

```
indices = [0, 1, 2, ..., n)
shuffle(indices)
for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    allocate(resource[i], indices[i])
}
```